# Eloquent return amount of relation AND a bool if the user has the relation aswell

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a model for "novels" which are "bookmarkable" and have "bookmarks"

I would like to show the amount of bookmarks a novel has and to determine if the currently logged in user bookmarked the novel.

```php
App\Novel::withCount('chapters', 'bookmarks')
           ->with(['author', 'ratings'])
           ->newestPublished()
           ->paginate(10)
```

This shown call works perfectly fine. However i'd love to see directly on the result if the current user has bookmarked the novel.

For the count of the bookmarks i built the following into my novel Model

```php
public function getBookmarksCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->bookmarks()->count();
}
```

Can I somehow create ANOTHER "getBookmarksCountAttribute" method which then works like this

```php
public function getUserBookmarkCountAttribute()
{
    if ( !Auth::user() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->bookmarks()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first() ? true : false;
}
```

Is there a way to easily add this to my query?

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for but you shouldn't be checking if user is logged in, in a model. You should be using the auth middleware in the controller

Comment: it's not about checking if he's logged in. Basically the response just depends on wether hes logged in or not since both - logged in and logged out users can call this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results) results the first result or null.

## Solution

```
public function getUserBookmarkCountAttribute()
{
    if ( !Auth::user() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return !is_null($this->bookmarks()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first());
}
```

## Alternative Solution

```
public function getUserBookmarkCountAttribute()
{
    if ( !Auth::user() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->bookmarks()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first() instanceof Bookmark;
}
```

## Tip 1

You can add the attribute to the [`$appends`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) array, so you don't need to store the count in your table explicitly.

## Tip 2

Using the Auth facade in your model is not a good practice. Better is to pass the user object / id to the model with Dependency Injection.

Comment: thanks! this is workingv ery will, I'll change it to pass the user to the function